# openjdk@11 is already installed but not found in JavaVirtual Machines folder

Tags: installation, java, uninstall, openjdk, macos-ventura

I am working on macOS ventura 13.2.1
If i run

`brew install openjdk@11`

i get

> Warning: openjdk@11 11.0.18 is already installed and up-to-date.

java -version gives me

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
```

Also if i go to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines its empty (i have deleted all jdk files)

I would like to uninstall all traces of java and install openjdk@11 again